# Changing an image from main.m in iOS5/Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, iboutlet

So I have an iOS5 application (xcode 4.2) where I have a viewcontroller with a UIImageView set to a certain image. I would like to change this image to another image after 2 seconds. There is no user interaction, and the only thing that needs to happen is for the image to change after 2 seconds. I found information on dispatch_time, so I tried that.

If you type dispatch_time in main.m, it gives you a few lines of code and you need to insert what it should do after 2 seconds. My questions:

1. Is the dispatch_time code indeed meant to go in main.m ? Assume that this application does nothing else than change the UIImageView to display another image after 2 seconds.
2. How do I reference the UIImageView from main.m? The declaration in the view controller .h file is like this:

   @property (weak, noatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *Image;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the dispatch code in your view controller, probably in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    ...

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
        self.Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anotherImage.png"];
    });
}
```

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. How do I define myImage though? I am trying with things like self.Image.image = @"image2.jpg" and ="image2.jpg" but that does not work

Comment: Use the [`imageNamed:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:) function of `UIImage` to do that. I've edited my code above to include an example of that.

Comment: Great!!! That did it, and I see you updated your code above already. Accepting your answer!

Answer (score 0):

No, it shouldn't go into main.m. You should put it into your view controller's init or viewDidLoad: method.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
```

self.imageView.image = otherImage;
    });